# Tests with Azure storage return null fields in a table

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am working with Azure Storage. I made the connections for the Token table and I get the values ​​correctly. But in another table I only get values ​​from 3 fields and the other 4 return as null.

this is my model:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BoltonInfo  extends TableServiceEntity implements Serializable {
    private String boltonCode;
    private String boltonName;
    private String boltonType;
    private boolean isAltaVelocidad;
    private String boltonOrder;

}
```

this is my ServicesImpl:

```
private void processBalances(List<SaldosResponse> boltons, JsonNode jsonBucketsList, int productID) throws ParseException {
    List<String> listBucketCode = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (JsonNode infoBucket : jsonBucketsList) {
        if (infoBucket.has(BUCKETCOUNTERS) && !MONEY.equals(infoBucket.path(USAGETYPE).asText())) {
            listBucketCode.add(infoBucket.get("id").asText());
                }
    }
    List<BoltonInfo> boltonList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    listBucketCode.forEach(boltonCode -> {
        BoltonInfo response = new BoltonInfo();
        try {
            response = (BoltonInfo) cloudMethodServiceImpl.readEntity(configProperties.getBultonsTable(), boltonCode, boltonCode, BoltonInfo.class);
            boltonList.add(response);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
    });
```

The connection with the table readEntity:

```
public <T> Object readEntity(String table, String partitionKey, String rowKey, Object value) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException {
    Object response = null;
    CloudTable entity = initCloudTable().getTableReference(table);
    System.out.println("La tabla existe  ? " + entity.exists());
    Class<? extends TableEntity> tableEntity = (Class<? extends TableEntity>) value;
    TableOperation operation = TableOperation.retrieve(partitionKey, rowKey, tableEntity);
    response = entity.execute(operation).getResultAsType();
    return response;
}
```

the response returns four null fields:
[image]

this is the table with its fields
[image]